# Null Poiner Exception while configuring solr and sql server

Tags: java, solr, nullpointerexception

I am getting this error when i am trying to index a table from database on sql server:

```
SEVERE: Exception while processing: APPLICATION document : SolrInputDocument[{}]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select APP_ID from APPLICATION Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:591)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:241)
    ... 11 more

Jul 27, 2011 3:13:54 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: Full Import failed:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select APP_ID from APPLICATION Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:591)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:241)
    ... 11 more
```

My data-config.xml file is like this:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
          name="ds1"    
          driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"     
              url="jdbc:sqlserver://10.91.95.93;databaseName=RK_GAIP"
              user="guest" 
              password="password"/>
   <document>
        <entity dataSource="ds1" name="APPLICATION" query="select APP_ID from APPLICATION">

            <field column="APP_ID" name="app_id" />

        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Please tell what could be wrong in this 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you managed to find out any solutions ? I have the same problem and I can't manage to find out a solution.

LE:

I found the solution meanwhile, using [this article](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/lucene_solr_sql_server)

My dataSource is like this:

```
 <dataSource name="ds-1" type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=Test" user="sa" password="password" batchSize="100" convertType="false" autoCommit="true"/>
```

So what i have changed is the driver I am using to connect to MS SQL server.

Also, be aware that you need:

- To have the option "Allow TCP/IP connections" enabled for the SQL INSTANCE you're using
- To have the service SQL SERVER BROWSER started.

Hope it works for you too!

Comment: Yeah i found the solution. Actually i used some three driver files
msbase.jar, mssqserver.jar, msutil.jar

Comment: i've used  same article and dataSource but still i m getting same error. Is there another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that something is wrong with your database connection. Check url, username and password used to connect to the database.